# Spring Security: Only show login form when url parameter is present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway (2023.0.0) and Spring Boot (3.2.3) with `oauth2Login` and `formLogin`.

Currently when the application is opened i am redirected to the login page. On the login page i can choose between the form or select the OAuth provider (as expected).

I want to skip the login page by default and directly redirect to the OAuth provider. Only when the user uses a defined url parameter (e.g. `?local=true`) in the inital request i want to show the login page with the form.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http
        ...
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
        .formLogin(withDefaults())
        ...;


    return http.build();
}

@Bean
MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails userDetails = User
        .withUsername("admin")
        .password("{noop}admin")
        .roles("admin")
        .build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(List.of(userDetails));
}
```

I already tried to implement a custom `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        ...
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
        .formLogin(withDefaults())
        .exceptionHandling(c -> c.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint()))
        ...;

    return http.build();
}
```

```java
public class ConditionalAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private final RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint oauth2EntryPoint;
    private final RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint loginFormEntryPoint;

    public ConditionalAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        this.oauth2EntryPoint = new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/oauth-client");
        this.loginFormEntryPoint = new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final AuthenticationException ex) {
        return exchange
            .getSession()
            .map(session -> {
                if (session.getAttribute("local") != null) {
                    return true;
                }
                var local = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().containsKey("local");
                if (local) {
                    session.getAttributes().putIfAbsent("local", true);
                }
                return local;
            })
            .flatMap(local -> {
                if (local) {
                    return loginFormEntryPoint.commence(exchange, ex);
                } else {
                    return oauth2EntryPoint.commence(exchange, ex);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

But this leads to endless redirects. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Did you try using antMatchers("default-home-page-url").permitAll().anyRequest.authenticated  for http in springSecurityFilterChain. This will allow home page to come and no authentication happens. For other, authentication will happen.

Comment: Added the path but still it is not working. I have a feeling that `this.loginFormEntryPoint = new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");`isn't the correct way to redirect to the login endpoint. But I can not find in the spring security source code or documentation how the default works...

Comment: I also found `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` in spring security web but i can not find the spring-flux version of it...